# Websphere v8.5.5 where to add the api visibility in the server.xml of the server

Tags: java, rest, wink

Hello all i am hosting a restful webservice via the inbuilt jax-rs of websphere.Everything seems good.But when i try to return a json response it throws an error unsupported media type 415. After spending some time on it i found that

```
 <application
 location="${server.config.dir}/dropins/my-war-SNAPSHOT.war"
 id="mywar" name="mywar" type="war">
 <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party"/>
</application>
```

should be added to my server.xml of the server.I have just opened the server.xml and added the snippet near the last tag but the server crashed.

Client

```
@Path("/books")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LibraryServiceImpl implements LibraryService {

private LibraryDAO libDao = new LibraryImpl();

@Path("/getbooks")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
public Response getBooks(@QueryParam("format") String format)
        throws SQLException {
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(libDao.getAllBooks()) {}).build();
}
```

Web Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Sample</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>
    JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.nag.application.Config</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where can i add that snippet and how?Please help me out of this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved by just removing this

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

from my class.